# Reading Data in API response | iOS

Tags: ios, json, api, nsdata

I'm trying to integrate a login API in my iOS project. When i hit that API in browser it gives me correct JSON response. Whereas, when i call it in my app, i'm unable to read JSON. Code is as:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "myURL")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

    if error != nil {
          print (error)
     }
      do {
         //jsonDict is always nil
         if let jsonDict = try self.jsonFromData(data!) {
            print (jsonDict)
         }
       }
       catch {
          print ("hi")
        }    
    }
```

**jsonFromData** is as:

```
private func jsonFromData(jsonData: NSData) throws -> [NSDictionary]?
{
    var jsonDict: [NSDictionary]? = nil
    do
    {
        jsonDict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? [NSDictionary]
    }
    catch
    {
        throw(error)
    }

    return jsonDict
}
```

Response of API, when hit in browser is as:

[image]

Please help me, what i am doing wrong. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
I just checked that if i convert data to String, it gives correct value. i.e.

```
let string = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
print (string)
//OUTPUT: Optional({"Authenticated":true,"CustomerID":000,"CustomerName":"TEMP","Members":[{"MemberID":000,"MemberNumber":"000","MembershipID":00,"MembershipExpiration":"\/Date(1517464799000-0600)\/","ValidBuyerTypes":[0]}]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your code where you decode the JSON and the as? statement. You are trying to get an array of NSDictionary. Your JSON as printed contains a single dictionary, not an array.

Answer (score 1):

This looks right to me. The only thing I can think is that (despite what the string output looks like) the top level container of your response is *NOT* an `NSDictionary`. In your `jsonFromData` function, instead of assuming the result of `JSONObjecWithData` will be an `NSDictionary`, I would say:

```
let iDunnoWhatThisIs = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) // don't cast this to NSDictionary
```

and see what you get back. It should either be a dictionary or an array, however, since you have `NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments` set for the options, it's possible that it could be something else entirely. Start with making SURE you're actually getting back what you're assuming you are and go from there.

Comment: Yes, i fixed the issue this way. The response was in string (most probably). and then i type-casted the string to dictionary.. I'll share my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using NSKeyedUnarchiver instead:

```
jsonDict = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(jsonData)! as NSDictionary
```